Surface plots using Tikz
I want to show surface approximation plots, in which I have two variables called calculated and approximated. I need to show two 3D surface plots corresponding to these two variables, whose values are stored in .dat file. I want to have plot as shown in this SO answer. I am able to compile and run the code provided in the answer. However, when I try to make some dummy modifications i.e. adding another hard-coded plot, the code is not running.
My non-running Code:
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={violet}{rgb255=(25,25,122) rgb255=(238,140,238) color=(white)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=-exp(-(\x^2+\y^2)/1.3;
}]
\begin{axis}[
view={30}{20},
mesh/interior colormap name=violet,
colormap/viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2.5, zmax=0,
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    samples=4, % Reduced number of samples for demonstration
    domain=-2:2,
    domain y=-2:2,
    point meta=explicit,
] 
table {
    x y z
    -2 -2 -2
    -1 -2 -1.5
    0 -2 -1
    1 -2 -0.3
    2 -2 0.2
    -2 -1 -1.5
    -1 -1 -0.8
    0 -1 -0.3
    1 -1 0.2
    2 -1 0.7
    -2 0 -1
    -1 0 0.1
    0 0 0.7
    1 0 1.2
    2 0 1.5
    -2 1 0.2
    -1 1 0.6
    0 1 1
    1 1 1.3
    2 1 1.5
    -2 2 0.8
    -1 2 1
    0 2 1.3
    1 2 1.5
    2 2 1.8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

How to get a figure like below (Plus added plot using hard-coded or file-loaded values)?


Just a note: the function has an unclosed bracket. I haven't found a solution, however. Another thing I would note is that this does not work in lualatex, whereas it runs without error in pdflatex. It still does not generate the graph in pdflatex.

Credit: AI
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={violet}{rgb255=(25,25,122) rgb255=(238,140,238) color=(white)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
f(\x,\y)=-exp(-((\x)^2+(\y)^2)/1.3);
}]
\begin{axis}[
view={30}{20},
mesh/interior colormap name=violet,
colormap/viridis,
hide axis,
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=-2.5, zmax=0,
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    samples=4, % Reduced number of samples for demonstration
    domain=-2:2,
    domain y=-2:2,
    point meta=explicit,
    mesh/rows=5 % added
] 
table[row sep=\\, meta=meta] {
    x y z meta\\
    -2 -2 -2 -2\\
    -1 -2 -1.5 -1.5\\
    0 -2 -1 -1\\
    1 -2 -0.3 -0.3\\
    2 -2 0.2 0.2\\
    -2 -1 -1.5 -1.5\\
    -1 -1 -0.8 -0.8\\
    0 -1 -0.3 -0.3\\
    1 -1 0.2 0.2\\
    2 -1 0.7 0.7\\
    -2 0 -1 -1\\
    -1 0 0.1 0.1\\
    0 0 0.7 0.7\\
    1 0 1.2 1.2\\
    2 0 1.5 1.5\\
    -2 1 0.2 0.2\\
    -1 1 0.6 0.6\\
    0 1 1 1\\
    1 1 1.3 1.3\\
    2 1 1.5 1.5\\
    -2 2 0.8 0.8\\
    -1 2 1 1\\
    0 2 1.3 1.3\\
    1 2 1.5 1.5\\
    2 2 1.8 1.8\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thanks. For the example, I used the hard-coded data. But actually, I want to load the data from a .dat file. The data is organized in the same format as you have written in the hard-coded table However, it is not working. Could you please have a look at the data source file for the surface plot here: https://github.com/siddmittal/test/blob/main/dummy.dat

@skm My best guess would be to set mesh/rows=150, or however many rows there are. Your data is so huge that it lags my computer, so I can't compile it.

There are 75000 rows. Could you try to run using e.g. Overleaf. BAsed on your suggestion, I tried to adjust the x_min/_x_max values, mesh/rows values but still incomprehensible errors.

@skm that is too many rows for my overleaf

yes, but you were probably trying to copy paste the data into the table, however, in this case, we need to import the data from the file , something like table {dummy.dat}.

Please share the specific error messages you are getting, as well as the number of rows and columns

70501 rows (1st row contains x y z meta. Since there are so many errors, I cannot write all of them here in the comment. I have added my code at https://github.com/siddmittal/test/blob/main/dummy_figure.tex
However, some of the error are: Missing \endcsname inserted., Undefined control sequence, Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition etc.
